# How to accept a bodyless GET request with JSON as it's content type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

After migrating to ASP.NET Core 2.1 we have realized that some consumers of our API are sending GET requests with the `Content-Type` header set to `application/json`. Sadly, these requests have not been rejected in the past (even though they should have), nevertheless this still is a breaking change..

Since our consumers need to fix this issue on their end, and this will take some time, we would like to temporarily accept these requests so we're not stuck waiting for this.

The framework (correctly) rejects the request with the following error message: `"A non-empty request body is required."`

The action looks like this:

```
[Route("api/file/{id:guid}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(Guid id)
{
     // Some simple code here
}
```

The code inside the action isn't being reached as the error is already been thrown before it reaches the action (due to the incorrect request).

@Nkosi's solution resulted in the same response:

```
[HttpGet("api/file/{id:guid}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromRoute]Guid id)
{
     // Some simple code here
}
```

The (PHP) cURL that the consumer uses is this:

```
$ch = curl_init(self::API_URL."/file/".$id);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Application: APPKey ".$this->AppKey,
    "Authorization: APIKey ".$this->ApiKey
));
```

Removing the `"Content-Type: application/json",` line turns the request into a valid requests, so we're 99.9% sure that the addition of this header is the evildoer.

Comment: @Timmeh use the `HttpGet` attribute and also try using `FromRoute` to tell the action exactly where to bind the id from.

Comment: @Nkosi Same issue, I'll edit my question to show you what I did. I'm guessing we'll need something more rigorous to get the framework to accept an invalid request.

Comment: ..and how does the consumer request look like? Can you give us an curl example or similar?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the information provided. You might need a [reprex].

Comment: @IMujagic Added the consumer request (PHP cURL, unsure how to see the result cURL)

Comment: @KirkLarkin How did you test this? I can't reproduce this with Postman/Insomnia, but I can with the consumer's PHP cURL (added to the post)

Comment: How is `API_URL` defined in your users code? if it's not like `http://example.com/api` they're receiving the right response.

Comment: @MasLoo It's a constant, I'm testing this locally and can see that the result URL (concatted with the Guid) is correct.

Comment: Try `{id:Guid}` instead of `{id:guid}` or just `{id}`. Also can you provide the controller attributes? Actually it should work as is, because Guids are treated as simple types and by default expected to be provided by the route or query, but not by body especially since GET requests must ignore the body.

Comment: I'm specifically talking about `/api` part. Is it possible that clients are calling your method like `http://localhost:8000/file/{id}` instead of `http://localhost:8000/api/file/{id}`?

Comment: @MasLoo Yes, the `/api` part is there.

Comment: @ckuri  `guid` is the correct way to use that route constraint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0#route-constraint-reference

Comment: @ckuri The only attribute on the controller is `[ApiController]`. All I need to do to fix this from the consumer side is removing the Content-Type header. Edited my question to show that.

Comment: You can try disabling the inbuilt model validation which is called before the controller action is hit via your startup class. `services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options => { options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true; });`

Comment: @Timmeh have you considered adding a middleware that inspects the request and removes the header for get requests

Comment: @Nkosi Literally what I was thinking about whilst trying out JConstantine's comment. Could even only remove the headers for the few GETs of which we know are the issue.

Comment: @Timmeh you can also turn the middleware on/off from a configuration file if you inject, that way you don't need to make app changes to "fix" your API at a later date

Comment: @Charleh Nice, I like it. Although we do want to get rid of this asap :)

Comment: @JConstantine Results in other issues and also turns off validation for the entire API, I prefer removing the Headers in a filter/middleware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider removing the header in a middleware early in the pipeline.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
    app.Use(async (context, next) => {
        var request = context.Request;
        var method = request.Method;
        IHeaderDictionary headers = request.Headers;
        string key = "Content-Type";
        if (method == "GET" && request.Headers.ContainsKey(key)) {
            headers.Remove(key);
        }

        // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
        await next();
    });

    //...
}
```

Comment: Currently doing this a bit later (in a filter) so authentication has been performed, but nevertheless accepting this as it would work the same.

Comment: Especially since this would just be a temporary fix till the customer fixes their side.

Comment: Which will probably be "Soon™"